# Python Tkinter: Graphics only update once in the mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been working on a 3D graphics program in Python Tkinter and the general idea is that I have a main function that resets and then changes all of the 3D coordinates based on the rotate values. It then takes these points and draws the forward facing triangles using the create_line function. Then finally I want the screen to update to show all the lines that have been drawn. This should all then repeat while changing the rotation values to slowly turn it each time.

Now what actually happens is it does all the math stuff correctly and it creates all the lines correctly but will only actually update the screen on the first iteration. I have done a lot of debugging and it DOES repeatedly do all the math and run the function that contains the create_line function. So it clearly has something to do with the root.update() function or how I am using the mainloop() function.

I have looked at like every other post on this stuff and there isn't anyone with the same issue unfortunately so I had to make my own post.

I have tried the following and I will update the list if I think of more:

- just using root.update() inside a while loop (had the same problem of it only updating once)
- what is in my current code which I will put below (using root.mainloop() and after())
- just a root.mainloop() which of course didnt work

Here is my current code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('475x375')

w = 400
h = 400

win = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
win.configure(bg="black")
win.pack()

sortedPos = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

colors = ["#ffffff","#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff","#ff00ff","#ffff00","#ff0000","#ffffff","#ff00ff","#0000ff","#ffff00","#00ff00"]
c = ""

def centeredLine(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    win.create_line(x1 + w/2, (0-y1) + h/2, x2 + w/2, (0-y2) + h/2, fill=c)

def triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    y = y1
    while (y<y2):
        centeredLine(x1+(((x2-x1)/(y2-y1))*(y-y1)), y, x1+(((x3-x1)/(y3-y1))*(y-y1)), y)
        y += 1
    while (y<y3):
        centeredLine(x2+(((x3-x2)/(y3-y2))*(y-y2)), y, x1+(((x3-x1)/(y3-y1))*(y-y1)), y)
        y += 1

def sort(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    if ((x1*y2-x2*y1)+(x2*y3-x3*y2)+(x3*y1-x1*y3)<0):
        if (y1 < y2):
            if y1 < y3:
                sortedPos[0] = x1
                sortedPos[1] = y1
                if (y2 < y3):
                    sortedPos[2] = x2
                    sortedPos[3] = y2
                    sortedPos[4] = x3
                    sortedPos[5] = y3
                else:
                    sortedPos[2] = x3
                    sortedPos[3] = y3
                    sortedPos[4] = x2
                    sortedPos[5] = y2
            else:
                sortedPos[0] = x3
                sortedPos[1] = y3
                sortedPos[2] = x1
                sortedPos[3] = y1
                sortedPos[4] = x2
                sortedPos[5] = y2
        elif (y2 < y3):
            sortedPos[0] = x2
            sortedPos[1] = y2
            if (y1 < y3):
                sortedPos[2] = x1
                sortedPos[3] = y1
                sortedPos[4] = x3
                sortedPos[5] = y3
            else:
                sortedPos[2] = x3
                sortedPos[3] = y3
                sortedPos[4] = x1
                sortedPos[5] = y1
        else:
            sortedPos[0] = x3
            sortedPos[1] = y3
            sortedPos[2] = x2
            sortedPos[3] = y2
            sortedPos[4] = x1
            sortedPos[5] = y1
        triangle(sortedPos[0],sortedPos[1],sortedPos[2],sortedPos[3],sortedPos[4],sortedPos[5])

xPos = [60,60,60,60,-60,-60,-60,-60,0,0,0,0,37.08,37.08,-37.08,-37.08,97.08,97.08,-97.08,-97.08]
yPos = [60,60,-60,-60,60,60,-60,-60,97.08,97.08,-97.08,-97.08,0,0,0,0,37.08,-37.08,37.08,-37.08]
zPos = [60,-60,60,-60,60,-60,60,-60,37.08,-37.08,37.08,-37.08,97.08,-97.08,97.08,-97.08,0,0,0,0]

sX = []
sY = []

triangles1 = [0,0,8,4,8,9,8,12,0,2,2,2,6,6,6,10,10,10,11,11,11,7,7,7,3,3,3,7,7,7,15,15,15,11,11,11]
triangles2 = [16,1,1,5,5,5,4,8,8,0,16,17,14,4,18,14,12,2,2,17,3,6,10,11,13,1,16,19,18,5,5,9,1,7,15,13]
triangles3 = [1,8,9,18,4,8,14,14,12,12,0,16,4,18,19,6,14,12,10,2,17,19,6,10,1,16,17,18,5,15,9,1,13,15,13,3]

fovl = 310

def reset():
    win.delete("all")
    
    xPos = [60,60,60,60,-60,-60,-60,-60,0,0,0,0,37.08,37.08,-37.08,-37.08,97.08,97.08,-97.08,-97.08]
    yPos = [60,60,-60,-60,60,60,-60,-60,97.08,97.08,-97.08,-97.08,0,0,0,0,37.08,-37.08,37.08,-37.08]
    zPos = [60,-60,60,-60,60,-60,60,-60,37.08,-37.08,37.08,-37.08,97.08,-97.08,97.08,-97.08,0,0,0,0]
    sX = []
    sY = []

xDif = 0
yDif = 0

def rotateX(d):
    #Around X-axis: X = x; Y = y*cos(theta) - z*sin(theta); Z = y*sin(theta) + z*cos(theta);
    for i, val in enumerate(yPos):
        yPos[i] = val*math.cos(abs(d)) - zPos[i]*math.sin(d)
        zPos[i] = val*math.sin(d) + zPos[i]*math.cos(abs(d))

def rotateY(d):
    #Around Y-axis: X = x*cos(theta) + z*sin(theta); Y = y; Z = z*cos(theta) - x*sin(theta);
    for i, val in enumerate(xPos):
        xPos[i] = val*math.cos(abs(d)) + zPos[i]*math.sin(d)
        zPos[i] = zPos[i]*math.cos(abs(d)) - val*math.sin(d)

def to2D():
    for i, val in enumerate(xPos):
        sX.append(round(fovl/(fovl+zPos[i])*val))
        sY.append(round(fovl/(fovl+zPos[i])*yPos[i]))

def main():
    global c
    global yDif
    reset()
    rotateX(xDif)
    rotateY(yDif)
    to2D()
    for i, val in enumerate(triangles1):
        c = (colors[int(i/3)])
        sort(sX[val],sY[val],sX[triangles2[i]],sY[triangles2[i]],sX[triangles3[i]],sY[triangles3[i]])
    yDif += 10
    print("done")
    root.after(0, root.update())
    root.after(1000, main)

main()
root.mainloop()
```

To hopefully make it a bit more digestible here is what the main function does more specifically:

- Sets all of the 3D coordinates to their original values and clears the canvas
- Changes the 3D coordinates based on how much I want them to rotate on the x-axis
- Changes the 3D coordinates based on how much I want them to rotate on the y-axis
- Converts the 3D coordinates to 2D screen coordinates
- Start making triangles
- Sets the c variable based on the color of the triangle I am currently trying to draw
- Sorts the screen coordinates of the current triangle by y-value
- Draws the current triangle layer by layer using create_line()
- Moves on to next triangle
- Repeat for all triangles (currently 36 I believe)
- After all of that change the y-rotation value by 10
- Print "done" for debugging purposes to show that the main function is repeating
- Run after(0, root.update()). Thought this could make a difference but it didn't it's the same as root.update()
- Run after(1000, main) to repeat this after 1 sec

  If you want more info all you have to do is ask :)

Comment: Remove the `root.after(0, root.update())` as it's unneeded (and might cause problems). Apart from that the `tkinter` part of your program works fine (it calls the `main` function every 1000 milliseconds). I noticed that the `reset` function doesn't actually modify the global variables. Maybe you missed `global xPos, yPos, sX, sY`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was quite the oversight. I'm not sure how I convinced myself that those parts were actually working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to TheLizzard for the answer! It wasn't an issue with Tk after all

Comment: Stackoverflow is NOT normal forum. Here is place for answer/solutin, not for message for someone. You should do it in comment. If some idea works for you then you can write it as answer - so other people could use this solution when they will have similar problem.

Comment: Here is a place for ask and answer questions, so do NOT message someone in as answer to a question!